# After set id to identity, the post function for my api doesnt work

Tags: c#

```
 "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Users' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.",
```

I used code first migration and when I add-migration, i changed the code shows up and added identity:true to my primary key: userId.

Then after that, my post api failed.

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class User
{
    public byte UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: We cannot add values explicitly to identity column when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to false

Comment: could you please add your entity for that you tried to set identity true?

Comment: @User965207 So, is there a good way to directly do it in visual studio? Should I modify my code first since I am using code-first migration?

Comment: @ershoaib Should I set the entity true in my code? Or directly changing database?

Comment: `update-database` <= fire this command in package manager console after setting identity true in your model

Comment: could you please add your class or entity that you set identity true? so I can get clear idea what you have to do

Comment: @ershoaib I have attached my code above. I am not pretty sure if this is the entity. This is the model I used to generate the database.

Comment: why you are making your `UserId` as `byte`? is not good to take it as `int` or `long`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179614/discussion-between-ershoaib-and-william-shu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to change your datatype for property `UserID` from `byte` to `int` and add `[Key]` attribute to it so it can be treated as your primary key in table

   ```
   [Key]
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   ```
2. Open package manager console and add migration by assigning name of your migration to below command

   ```
   add-migration YourMigrationName
   ```
3. Then after successful of step 2 update your database with latest changes in your added migration

   ```
   update-database
   ```

Try once may it help you

Comment: @William Shu, view the answer might be it help you :)